flutter CachedNetworkImage headers are incorrect
The headers are incorrect for both CachedNetworkImageProvider and CachedNetworkImage I think and I am curious if there is a workaround, or if that is intentional or a bug.
CachedNetworkImage(
    imageUrl: "https://myurl.com/api/pubmedia?mediaid=${mediaurls[i]}",
    httpHeaders: {auth:"123"},
    placeholder: (context, url) => CircularProgressIndicator(),
    errorWidget: (context, url, error) => Icon(Icons.error), 
    imageRenderMethodForWeb: ImageRenderMethodForWeb.HttpGet       
)

On the server I wrote code to print out all the headers. Without "imageRenderMethodForWeb: ImageRenderMethodForWeb.HttpGet" the headers are NOT passed at all. So that seems like a bug. With imageRenderMethodForWeb it prints the header key as a value in another header so
HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS: auth

and "123" is not included anywhere in the header information. Additionally if I include the headers, the widget gets stuck loading the image forever and never returns. Right now my server doesn't do anything with the headers besides prints them so the images load perfect without the headers or withouth imageRenderMethodForWeb. The exact same thing happens with CachedNetworkImageProvider and the "headers" parameter.
My question is why is it using the header key auth (its a string above) and inserting it into the value field "HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS" and why does it discard the "123" and why does it never complete when the header is provided?
Thank you in advance for any insight.

ok I stumbled on the answer and its super complicated so I wanted to post how this whole thing works. This is the result of CORS functionality and my server had to be custom modified to handle this interaction. If your backend url is not the same as your domain the CachedNetworkImage will automatically generate a CORS request ONLY if you add in headers. So that should be documented. If your headers are
httpHeaders: {"myheader":"thisisatest"},

then during the preflight it will tell you the headers to expect and it calls them access control headers with
HTTP_ACCESS_CONTROL_REQUEST_HEADERS: myheader

and the request type is OPTIONS. you need to add the following headers in response
("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin),
("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, OPTIONS')
('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, myheader')

then you need to return
204 No Content

then in the next request you will get
HTTP_MYHEADER: thisisatest

and you can do whatever you need. note
origin comes from teh value of HTTP_ORIGIN in teh first request. it can also be set to "*" for testing. handled in raw python wsgi request if you want to see it the code is below for understanding
def application(env, start_response):
        request_headers = {key: value for key, value in env.items() if key.startswith('HTTP_')}
        reqhead = "\n".join(f"{key}: {value}" for key, value in request_headers.items())

        method = env["REQUEST_METHOD"]
        origin = env.get("HTTP_ORIGIN")
        cookie = env.get("HTTP_COOKIE", "N/A")
        cors = origin
        preflight = cors and method == "OPTIONS"

        headers = [("Content-Type", "text/plain")]
        if cors:
            headers.extend([
                ("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", origin),
                ("Access-Control-Allow-Credentials", "true")
            ])
            if preflight:
                headers.extend([
                    ('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET, POST, OPTIONS'),
                    ('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, myheader')
                ])
        else:
            headers.append(("Set-Cookie", "auth=fnd"))

        if method == "OPTIONS":
            start_response("204 No Content", headers)
            return [b'']

